# Return the correct type from Task<List<T>>

Tags: c#

I am getting an error  which is  "Cannot implicity convert type ....... "

from this function

```
Task<List<JOB>>  GetJobsForTheDay(entities ctx,DateTime T,DateTime T2)
    {
        return ctx.JOBS.Where(a => a.BOOKEDAT <= T && a.BOOKINGTIME >= T2).ToList();
    }
```

I am not sure how to return the correct type. I have tried casting 
`(Task<List<JOB>>)`

but to no avail.

Comment: So you're writing a method that's not asynchronous, but for some reason you want to wrap its return value in a Task?

Comment: I want the function to run asynchronous - but guess it's wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `FromResult`:

```
return Task.FromResult(ctx.JOBS.Where(a => a.BOOKEDAT <= T && a.BOOKINGTIME >= T2).ToList());
```

but you should really execute the query asynchronously rather than blocking and returning a completed task.

If you're using entity framework 6 you could do:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

return ctx.JOBS.Where(a => a.BOOKEDAT <= T && a.BOOKINGTIME >= T2).ToListAsync();
```